# currentIndex to have onPressed function

Tags: flutter, indexing

I am making a flutter app and i am working on the bottom navigation bar and i want to know if i can make the buttons to redirect the user to a new page UI from the app.I used this 'package:bubble_bottom_bar/bubble_bottom_bar.dart' and i don't know how to cal currentIndex = 1 ,2,3,4 to redirect to a new page when the user pressed the icon. I tried to add to my   BubbleBottomBarItem a onPressed action but it doesn't work.
This is the code that i am using

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tariffo/favoriteProviders.dart';
import 'package:tariffo/messages_list.dart';
import 'package:bubble_bottom_bar/bubble_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'HomePage.dart';

class BarDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BarDetailState createState() => _BarDetailState();
}

class _BarDetailState extends State<BarDetail> {
  int currentIndex;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentIndex = 0;
  }

  changePage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8),
      child: BubbleBottomBar(
        opacity: 0.2,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16.0)),
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        hasInk: true,
        inkColor: Colors.black12,
        hasNotch: true,
        fabLocation: BubbleBottomBarFabLocation.end,
        onTap: changePage,
        items: <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Colors.black),
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Colors.red),
              title: Text("Home")),
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.black),
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Colors.red),
              title: Text("Saved")),
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Colors.red),
              title: Text("Search")),
          BubbleBottomBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.black),
              activeIcon: Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Colors.red),
              title: Text("Messages")),
        ],
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

and this are the pages that i want the buttons to open : FavoriteProviders(),MessageList()

Comment: updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

1. A list of pages:

   ```
   final List<Widget> _pages = [
     FavoriteProviders(),
     MessageList()
   ];
   ```
2. A `Scaffold` where the `body: _pages[currentIndex],`

   ```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       bottomNavigationBar: _bubbleBottomNavBar(),
       body: _pages[currentIndex],
     )
   }
   ```

where `_bubbleBottomNavBar()` is your bottom bar.

**OR**

Replace on `onTap` function with:

```
BubbleBottomBar(
    opacity: 0.2,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16.0)),
    currentIndex: currentIndex,
    hasInk: true,
    inkColor: Colors.black12,
    hasNotch: true,
    fabLocation: BubbleBottomBarFabLocation.end,
    onTap: (index) {
     if(index == 1)
       Navigator.push(
         context,
         MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FavoriteProviders()),
       );
     if (index == 2)
       Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MessageList()),
       );
     },
    items: <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
     [...]
    ]
)
```

Comment: where i should add this onTap function?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Or you can keep `changePage` function, but remove `setState` and onTap.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about it is by using `PageView`, create a `PageController` and assign it to the property of `PageView` called `controller`.

The controller - `PageController _controller = PageController();`

The PageView itself

```
PageView(
    controller: _controller;
    children: <Widget>[
        FavoriteProviders(),
        MessageList()
    ]
)
```

So `FavoriteProviders()` is now index 0, and `MessageList()` is now index 1
You can use one of these in the onTap to navigate to that page

`_controller.jumpToPage(index)` or
`controller.animateToPage(index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeIn)`

Pass in whatever you want for the duration and curve.